# How to center a span element in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have three `<span>` elements that I want to place horizontally one after the other. I also need the middle element to be at the center of the page (horizontally), but `margin:auto; width: 100px` is not working since it is a `<span>`. If I make it `<div>`, there is a line break.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: sorry, i did read question incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use three identical `span` elements of 100px width, with `display: inline-block` nested inside a `div` with `text-align` set to center: http://jsfiddle.net/e9sru/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <span class="inner">
        <div class="overflow">Lorem ipsum dolor est mori. I am overflowing but still to the left of number two</div>
    </span>
    <span class="inner">Two</span>
    <span class="inner">Three</span>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container {
    text-align: center;
}

.inner {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
}

.overflow {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you create one div and set that to have a width of 100%. Inside this dive you create 3 more divs; one for each element. If you set each element to have a width of 33.3% then it will centre the middle one and the other 2 accordingly. Like wise you can add margins to decrease the 33.3%. For example margin: 0 3% 0 3% on the centre div would give it 3% margin on the left and right. Minus 6% from the size of the div width as it must always total 100%

Answer (score 0):

`span` is an inline element, so it doesn't behave like a `div` which is a block element.

I suggest doing a mix of floats and align center.

Example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="block element3">ELEMENT3</span>
<span class="block element1">ELEMENT1</span>
<span class="block element2">ELEMENT2</span>
```

**CSS**

```
.block {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
}
.element3 {
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
.element2 {
    float: left;
    background-color: green;
}
.element1 {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: blue;
    width: auto;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

http://jsfiddle.net/YUCv2/1/