# CSS: using text-align: center in span

Tags: css, html, text-align

For a calendar app, I want to have the familiar look of the month name centered with a left arrow at the left margin to go back a month and the right arrow at the right margin to go forward a month. Something like `<     May    >`

`<Div>`s insert line breaks at the end so I thought I would use span except span is an inline element so that the `text-align: center` property only aligns it within the length of the month. Just using `text-align: center` produces something like `<May        >`

To compensate for this, I have added `display: block` in the span, however, this creates a line break at the end ie

```
<     May
              >
```

Can anyone suggest a proper way to do this?

Last version:

**CSS/HTML:**

```css
span.previous {
     float:left;
}
span.next {
     float:right;    
}
span.month {
     display:block;
     text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<span class="previous"><img src="leftarrow.gif"></span>
<span class = "month">May</span>
<span class="next"><img src="rightarrow.gif"></span>
```

Comment: Why you need `display: block;` when you want to align everything inline?

Comment: because otherwise text-align does not work..middle example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to center a span element in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15324452/how-to-center-a-span-element-in-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to apply the text-align to the container element, and remove `display:block` (text-align works with inline/inline-block elements). And don't forget to clear the floats after the container.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kkJ8e/)

Comment: This is enough, why use floats and clears and all stuff http://jsfiddle.net/C3Wxf/

Comment: It looks like OP wants a full width layout for this, with arrows on the edges, probably something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/kkJ8e/1/)

Comment: This worked.  I guess the answer to my original question is that you can only text-align center in a div...you cannot do it in a span.  FYI, I tried using inline-block and adding a width but that did not center either.

Comment: You can text-align **inline** elements in any **block** element, it doesn't matter what type of element they are

Answer (score 1):

One way to design your calendar header could be the following.
In my example ([this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Ax2ug/)), I used an asterisk instead of an image.
I replaced the month span for a paragraph and changed the order of your markup.

Asterisks or images will be kept at the sides and the month in the middle in a flexible design.
See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fico/Ax2ug/).

```css
#header {
    background:#e0e0e0;
}
span.previous {
    float:left;
}
span.next {
    float:right;    
}
p.month {
    text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
    <span class="previous">**</span>
    <span class="next">**</span>
    <p class = "month">May</p>
</div>
```